# I want to use Google Maps API, but with 3D buildings on my React.JS code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-maps-api-3

what im trying to do is create a map of my university, but i want it to be on 3D, so if someone wants to look for an specific classroom on the 3rd floor he would be able to rotate the map and see it, instead of Google Maps API 2D option, in where you can just see it from above. The thing here is that i need it on JS code, so i can use it on my React.js project and i'm looking foward to generate every point inside the map from a Database. Because i want the user to be able to use a filter box, so he can search for an specific point, and locate it using the coordinates. 
I'm trying with Babylon, but this demo is too heavy:

https://axeon.fr/CLIENT/EIFFAGE/Bordeaux.Hyperion/#/MAQUETTE_RT/index.html

My first idea came from the Google Maps API, need to do the same thing, but using 3D buildings.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic here; see [ask] and the other material in the [help].

Comment: Ohh, sorry, thanks for the update

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can display your map in 2D using whatever API you would like and define pins on the Map for your predefined Point of Interests (POI). Once clicked, you can change the view to 3D mode and display the canvas which is attached to your 3D rendering engine such as Babylon which takes care of displaying the building and all those 3D interactions you would like to offer your users. At any point in time, the user can toggle between 2D map and 3D scene and go and choose another POI. Basically the 2D map component just passes the POI ID to the 3D component and it loads the required shapes. Also it may be good idea to take a look at [cesium](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium) which is an open-source JavaScript library for world-class 3D globes and maps.

Comment: Oh! on that way, wouldnt be necessary render the entire 3D map, just the building  attached to the certain POI, right?

Comment: Yes, in case you are using Babylon, you just pass the POI ID to the component then init your Babylon scene and import/draw your meshes and wire up necessary events and on the '2D toggle Map' button, you dispose your meshes and do proper cleanup to free memory and finally get rid of the canvas. I am not sure why I get a negative point on this answer?!

Comment: Thanks Hamed! good idea, i will try it out. 
not sure about the negative point, but i 've selected your answer as my solution. Thanks, for real!